# Michigan Upper Peninsula Hiking - Long Trail

Tags: hiking, united-states

I am trying to find a long trail in Michigan's upper peninsula for myself and 3 friends to hike.

We plan on hiking for 7-9 days, and cannot seem to find a trail that is long enough to accommodate that.

SO, what are some hiking trails in the UP long enough to travel on for a minimum of 7 days?

Comment: You say 7-9 days, I suggest using two of those days to travel to and from the mountains where there are a lot of week long trails.

Comment: @shemseger do you know specific trail names? Yes, the 7-9 days is used for traveling as well. I'll add that to my post.

Comment: If you're already going to the UP, you could cross the sea and head to Isle Royale.

Comment: @ShemSeger: The nearest "real" mountain range from there (Bighorns) is a good 16 hour drive minimum, and you'd need awhile to sleep, so you'd really be replacing up to 30% of your adventuring with sitting in a car. Doesn't sound like a good exchange when there is plenty of great backcountry adventuring to be done in the Great Lakes region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do want to stay in the Michigan area, you might want to check out the [North Country Trail](https://northcountrytrail.org/trail/) . As a disclaimer, I've never done any of the sections in Michigan, but I the section I hiked in Pennsylvania/New York was really nice. There are thousands of miles in the trail, so you can't really get bored. There are some sections that are connected by roads and bridges, however, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi Beznus, I appreciate the suggestion! I'll take a look at it over lunch. If it's as awesome as you say, sounds great!

Comment: Michigan and Wisconsin are some of the most beautiful areas in the country, and I've been to some of the biggest national parks. What I like most about the Great Lakes area is that not many people do thru hiking and its not very crowded. Mostly local people doing small sections. On some of the more well know parks it feels like I'm visiting a tourist attraction, but the North Country Trail is nice and empty. I'm actually thinking about doing some of the Michigan/Wisconsin sections this summer.

Comment: That's very useful to know because in looking for a more secluded route myself. The website you have is excellent, I glanced it over a little (+1). I live in Southeast Michigan and love the state, especially for someone who plans on backpacking consistently.

Comment: Cool! Have a great time. I was talking to one of my friends about this trail after my comment and he mentioned there being lots of mosquitoes, just another thing to consider.

Comment: We were assuming it would be pretty bad - especially with the weather we have been having this summer, so that isn't too big of a deal. Do you have any recommendations on how to repel them most efficiently? Otherwise I don't think it would be unbearable to go in without any repellent.

Comment: Well I've read that you can apply [Permethrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permethrin) to hammocks to keep the bugs off. I don't see why you couldn't do it with clothes, but I don't know if I like the idea of using a bunch of chemicals. The largest part of them come out at night and as long as you're inside your shelter after dark, you should be okay.

Comment: @Beznus: Permethrin is meant to be put on your clothes.